# How to filter log entries based on regexp and math condition?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

So, here is log entry example:
`bla-bla-bla some data, "valuableParameter":239, bla-bla, other parameters`

The question is, how to get only log entries with `valuableParameter` greater then 100?

So, I tried 
`grep -P '"valuableParameter":/K(/d+)'` - extract value, `239`, nice

`(( $(grep -P '"valuableParameter":/K(/d+)') > 100 ))` - fail `syntax error in expression (error token is "80`

It's obvious, that I'm pretty noob with bash and perl regexping, so any help would be useful.

Should I use `-Po`? `awk`?

Answer (score 1):

**One line really simple in Bash**

```
grep -oP '"valuableParameter":\K(\d+)' test.txt | while read -r number; do echo "$number" | ((number > 100)) && echo "$number"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

with awk

```
awk -F',|:' '($3>100){print $3}'
```